# When I make a compilation, I create an error in magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

Every time I try to make a compilation it shows me this error and I do not know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 28 secs 252.0 MiB

[ReflectionException]
Class Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface does not exist

[ReflectionException]
Class Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide 777 permission on **generated** folder on the root of magento installation.Please use commands given below before compilation:-

- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- sudo rm -rf generated/*
- sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Also if there is permissions issue then you can use sudo before commands

Comment: 777 seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like permission issue, Please set proper file permission

Run Below command to set proper file permission :

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For local development set pub and var to 775 or 777

Answer (score 0):

The class `Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface` does not current exist since Magento 2.2, replace it with `Magento\Framework\Acl\Data\CacheInterface`